# How to simulate the hidden states from a HMM conditioned on the observed sequence?

Tags: hidden-markov-model

Given a heterogenous (discrete) Hidden markov model with hidden states, $x_1, \dots, x_n$ and observed states $o_1, \dots o_n$, known transition matrices $T_1, \dots, T_n$ and emission matrices $E_1, \dots, E_n$ and initial probability vector $I_1$, how can one simulate hidden state sequences from the distribution

$$ (x_1, \dots, x_n) | (o_1, \dots, o_n)?$$

Comment: Check the [forward-backward algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward%E2%80%93backward_algorithm).

Comment: Hi @svendvn are you looking for a software package to do this or are you asking for an explanation on how the sequence simulation is carried out?

Comment: Hi @ShaunWilkinson. I am looking for an explanation, not a software package